How do I find the zero-input response using the state transition matrix for a linear time-varying system?
I've been given the matrix as follows. I'm supposed to find its zero-input response for initial conditions $x(0)=[1,1]$
$$
\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{-t} \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} x
$$
I find
$$
\dot{x_1} = x_1 + e^{-t}x_2 \to x_1 = t*x_1(0) - e^{-t}*x_2(0)
$$
$$
\dot{x_2} = 0 \to x_2=x_2(0)
$$
I use conditions $x_1(0) = 1, x_2(0)=0$ and $x_1(0) = 0, x_2(0)=1$ to obtain the fundamental matrix and its inverse
$$
 \Psi = \begin{bmatrix} t & -e^{-t} \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
 \Psi^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/t & e^{-t}/t \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
therefore the state-transition matrix is
$$
 \Psi(t)*\Psi^{-1}(t_0)=\Phi(t,t_0) = \begin{bmatrix} t/t_0 & te^{-t}/t_0-e^{-t} \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
That seems fine, but now how do I actually evaluate the zero-input response given the initial value? I know I'm supposed to solve for $x(t)=\Phi(t,0)x(0)$ but if I plug in 0 for $t_0$ to get $\Phi(t,0)x(0)$, I would get a divide by 0 error. I cannot find a single example online where anyone actually uses or fully solves out a LTV problem.

I think you were thinking to a kind of Laplace-traform approach to compute the fundamental/state-transition matrix, but I think something went wrong.
I propose an alternative way (and in my point of view, easier) to find the exact solution, toghether with the fundamental/state-transition matrix.
Since the first equation become $x_1'(t)=x_1(t)+e^{-t}x_2(0)$ we have
$$x_1(t)=e^{t}x_1(0)+\int_0^t e^{t-s}e^{-s}x_2(0)\;ds=e^{t}x_1(0)+\frac{1}{2}e^t(1-e^{-2t})x_2(0)=e^{t}x_1(0)+\frac{1}{2}(e^t-e^{-t})x_2(0).$$ (By applying variation of constants method, for example).
This already gives us the solution in a closed form, for any $(x_1(0),x_2(0))\in \mathbb{R}^2$. On the other hand, this also provides us an expression for the state-transition matrix. Indeed one has
$$
\Phi(t,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & \frac{1}{2}(e^t-e^{-t})\\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and, after some manipulations, also has
$$
\Phi(t,t_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{(t-t_0)} & \frac{1}{2}(e^{t-2t_0}-e^{-t})\\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm a bit confused at the end there, how did you manage to get the t0 terms in there?

You can use, as you correctly said in your question, the properties of the state-transition matrix, and thus compute $\Phi(t,t_0)$ by
$$
\Phi(t,t_0)=\Phi(t,0) \Phi^{-1}(t_0,0).
$$
Or, equivelently, you can directly solve the ODE with new initial conditions $(x_1(t_0),x_2(t_0))\in \mathbb{R}^2$, again using variation of constants method for the $x_1$-equation.
